# advance url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

how can i change

http://www.mydomain.com/down.php?key=1223

to

http://www.mydomain.com/?k=1223

i have google it but not found any ans...please help me...

i am using apache server with unix

Comment: Using what web server? IIS? Apache? CERN httpd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use mod_rewrite. Add to your .htaccess file those lines:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^\s+\.php\?key=(\d+) \?k=$1
```

Read about mod_rewrite and RewriteRules here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=(.*)
RewriteRule /down.php /?k=%1 [R]
```